# 120000 logins for whole 1 hour using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My requirement is to perform 120000 logins and all these 120000 user sessions should be alive for whole 1 hour test duration using JMeter. Does this mean that we must use 120000 concurrent users (I'm afraid how many load generators it takes to generate such huge load) or this can be achieved by using less users too? Any other way to perform this scenario?

Comment: A session can be active/alive without an active TCP connection. You'd try this for several hours and make sure that the first session you created is still accessible at the peak and at the end of your test.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally yes, each JMeter thread (virtual user) must represent [real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

However if you don't want to keep the session active for 1 hour you can just configure JMeter to send [Connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header with the value of `keep-alive`. In JMeter it can be done by ticking `Use KeepAlive` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

Additionally you can provide [Keep-Alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) header via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to set the maximum time to keep the session open

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if I use 1000 concurrent users to make 120000 logins in an hour and set keep alive time for more than 1 hour in the header. Will it work?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't know.

Comment: Also, any idea on how many load generators would be needed (16 vCPU, 64 GB Ram,  Intel Xeon® Platinum 8175M processor) to generate a load of 120000 users.

Comment: I don't know again. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html). Set up monitoring of baseline OS health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.), it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics). Start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until any of monitored metrics start exceeding i.e. 80% of maximum available capacity. This is how many users you can mimic from particularly this machine for particularly this test. Divide 12000 by that number and you will get it.